# What is "Data Protection" option in WebBIOS 6.1-45-Rel of ServeRAID M5110e controller?

Tags: ibm-xseries, options, ibm

What is **"Data Protection"**`option in **WebBIOS 6.1-45-Rel** during creation of new Drive Group?
Server is **IBM x3650 M4** with **ServeRAID M5110e** controller.
User's Guide (here http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5086126) does not provide any details about it...

Comment: WARNING: take a look at this if you're considering enabling this option in a System x3650 M4 server. I had it enabled (no idea how, it's supposed to be off by default), and caused random controller errors (critical, fatal and catastrophic): https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/myportal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5093594

Answer (score 3):

there is no official documentation from IBM about this feature but our local dealer referred to the documentation directly from Seagate:

http://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/docs/pdf/whitepaper/tp621-safeguarding-data-from-corruption-us.pdf

EDIT (To avoid link rot): 
It states that the feature relies on the T10 Protection Information (T10-PI) standard which adds an extra eight bytes of information to the 512-byte sectors of hard drives, increasing sector size to 520 bytes. These extra eight bytes of metadata are used to verify the integrity of the 512 bytes of data in the sector. This should prevent data from silent corruption.
Due to the extra overhead of transferring PI metadata from the media, sequential performance of a PI drive will be reduced by approximately 1.56%.

Comment: Scutze, could you please summarize the contents of the linked file for SF readers? Otherwise your post is subject to linkrot.

Comment: This is the same protection feature that EMC/NetApp (and others) use in enterprise SAN's. Just for the record. :)

Comment: Looks like Seagate has changed the name of the file for the Whitepaper. The following link works: http://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/docs/pdf/whitepaper/safeguarding-data-from-corruption-technology-paper-tp621us.pdf